# How do I custom make a url in html?

Tags: html

In the main folder, I have index.html, contact.html and about.html. In my index.html, I have a link that can link to and open contact.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NEW HOME PAGE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>this is a new page</p>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link, the url goes from index.html to contact.html. What would I have to do so that I can nest contact.html inside index.html and the url should look like this. ...index/contact.html. I have multiple layers/branches and want to have a clear structure. For example: about.html will have few pages and should show url as about/team/players or about/team/coaches.

Comment: Please confirm that you're building a "static website" (comprised of only `*.html` pages, without any PHP, ASP.NET, JSP, server-side Node.js etc)? If so, if you use tooling like Dreamweaver (or FrontPage...) or a "static site generator" (as listed on https://www.staticgen.com/ - like Hugo and Elder.js) then they'll manage the generation of `href=""` and `src=""` paths for you automagically. If you're doing it by hand (and copying+pasting files) then you're in for a world of pain.

Comment: Hello, I am only using html and its a static website and only has 4-5 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on training HTML, you can create your files like this structure:

```
Your_project
|
|_index.html <-- /index.html
|_index_folder
  |
  |_contact.html <-- /index/contact.html
  |_privacy.html <-- /index/privacy.html
```

**Note:** It's just for learning, when you work with server, it may be different.

Comment: What is the purpose of `index_folder`?

Comment: @Dai Well, I just name that folder with a specific name. BTW, I think OP will be easier to classify `index` folder and `index` html file.